# Limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\cdot \sin(\frac{n}{n+1}\pi) = \pi$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

**Problem:**

$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\cdot \sin(\frac{n}{n+1}\pi) = \pi$

**So far I have:**

I think that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{ \sin(\frac{n}{n+1}\pi)}{\frac{n}{n+1}\pi} = 1$, but I'm not sure. It would be similar to $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, but that doesn't make a load of sense to me after trying to finish it.

Comment: The limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{ \sin(\frac{n}{n+1}\pi)}{\frac{n}{n+1}\pi} $$ does not go to 1. if you plug in $\infty$ you will end up dividing by zero.

Comment: Look for equivalent angles in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$n\cdot \sin(\frac{n}{n+1}\pi) = n\cdot \sin(\pi-\frac{1}{n+1}\pi) = n\cdot \sin(\frac{1}{n+1}\pi).$$

use replacement $u=\frac{1}{n+1}$, then $u \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$, also $n = \frac{1-u}{u}$. therefore

$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\cdot \sin(\frac{n}{n+1}\pi) = \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{1-u}{u} \cdot \sin(\pi u) = \pi \lim_{u\to 0} (1-u) \dfrac{\sin(\pi u)}{\pi u} = \pi \lim_{u\to 0} (1-u) \cdot \lim_{u\to 0}\dfrac{\sin(\pi u)}{\pi u}  = \pi.$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @David Mitra.

$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin(\frac{n}{n+1}\pi)=\lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin(\frac{1}{n+1}\pi)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n\pi}{n+1}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n+1}\pi)}{\frac{1}{n+1}\pi}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n\pi}{n+1}=\pi$